# Zend Framework Cache creates new file and doesnt load it

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

i'm having a little problem with Zend Framework Full Page Cache.
My current Bootstrap configuration looks like this:

```
    $dir = PUBLIC_PATH . "/tmp/";

    $frontendOptions = array(
        'lifetime' => 6000000000,
        'content_type_memorization' => true,
        'default_options'           => array(
        'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
        ),
        'regexps' => array(
            '^/.*' => array('cache' => true),       
        )
    );

    $backendOptions = array(
            'cache_dir' => $dir
    );

    // getting a Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page object
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page',
                         'File',
                         $frontendOptions,
                         $backendOptions);

    $cache->start();
```

which worked perfectly before changing our development system to the live one.

Now if we enable the caching system it creates the correct cached file in the correct path but doens't load it.

So for every request another cache file is created but the old one NEVER gets loaded.

Maybe anyone has had this problems before and can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there might be issue with permission to move from development environment to live.

The `tmp` directory is writable by myself and other users of the same group and also apparently Zend will access the files as another user. The solution was to `chmod 777` on the folder, making it writable.

let me know if i can help you more.